# Playing short words sounds, and sound file format?

Tags: iphone, ios, file-format, audio

I have an app with hundreds of short sounds (words mainly). I use:

```
 AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_soundID);
```

to play them.

The problem is that AudioServices isn't compatible with MP3-format files, so my files are pretty big and when I have hundreds of them, my app size is huge.

Is there a better way to play short sounds in a compressed format? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: why dont you use AVAudioPlayer ?

Comment: probably because im stupid. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mac/iPhone apple recommends to use .aiff format for playing short sounds.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Interchange_File_Format and http://images.apple.com/support/itunes_u/docs/iTunes_U_Creating_Content.pdf

Comment: Thanks. AAC is defiantly the choice. small and sounds great.